# How to enable output during debian/ubuntu preseeding

Tags: debian, ubuntu, preseed

I am setting up a preeseded configuration with a somewhat longer running `d-i preseed/late_command`, in fact downloading and executing an ansible playbook.

I am running a simple menu system with `vesamenu.c32`.

Is there a way to display stdout during the late_command instead of the progress bar?